# Which access rights to enable for using GetComputerObjectName?

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++

I would like to obtain the simple DisplayName for the computer via `GetComputerObjectName` like tried:

```
//Get the buffer size
    bRet = GetComputerObjectName(NameDisplay, NULL, & ulSize);
    if(!bRet)
    {
        DWORD dw = 0;
        dw = GetLastError();
        MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("Could not get the computer name size."), TEXT("Failure."), MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
        exit(-1);
    }

    //Create a buffer large enough to contain the display name
    pBuffer = new TCHAR[ulSize+1];

    //Obtain the computer object name
    bRet = GetComputerObjectName(NameDisplay, pBuffer, &ulSize);
    if(!bRet)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("Could not get the computer name."), TEXT("Failure."), MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
        exit(-1);
    }
```

But the call to `GetComputerObjectName` fails with **ERROR_CANT_ACCESS_DOMAIN_INFO.**
I already tried enabling the *privileges* *SE_SECURITY_NAME* and *SE_SYSTEM_PROFILE_NAME*,
but that does not work either.

Anyone knows how to do this?

Comment: I'm not sure what `NameDisplay` should actually return in the context of `GetComputerObjectName`, as [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724268(v=vs.85).aspx) only shows an example for `GetUserNameEx`. Could it be that you're running the code with a user, that is not a domain user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why dont u use the [`GetComputerNameEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724301%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.
Try something like below,

`ULONG sz = 0;

GetComputerNameEx(ComputerNameDnsFullyQualified, NULL,&sz);

cout << "size : " << (int)sz << endl;`

It works well. I just tried ur code on my machine in the network and it ddnt work well for me too. But this code gave the full name of the machine in the network. I guess it works in standalone machines too ( just like using [NET command](http://ss64.com/nt/net_useradmin.html) ).

Comment: thx for the note, but that's not what i asked for... Knowing how to solve the original issue may help with other problems alike...

Answer (score 0):

The error ERROR_CANT_ACCESS_DOMAIN_INFO normal show up if the machine is not part of a domain.
If you are sure it is part of the domain maybe check if a firewall is blocking on outgoing port 135.

Comment: Im using it to get the DisplayName for my own computer... why would i need to have access to the network outside?

Comment: I am not sure but I think the method is designed to talk to a MS  directory service by some RPC call. You could use the GetComputerName to get the same info.